# 重複したコメントに対して対処するには通報という手段でよろしいですか？

Tags: サポート

コメントは消されればこのリンク先も意味がなくなりますが、[[完全一致検索がしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48956/%E5%AE%8C%E5%85%A8%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84]%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%A7)、私の投稿に対してコメントが二重に投稿されています。<kbd>Enter</kbd>キーを改行目的で使用したためかもしれませんが、こうしたコメントがある事に気づき、かつ、コメント投稿者がしばらく現れないか、消す意志を有していない気配を察知したとき、通報という処理によって消していただくのは、適切な手段でしょうか？
もし勝手に消された場合でも、恐らくご本人様の文句は全くない部類の問題だろうとは思います。

Comment: ほっとけばいいんじゃないかとも思いました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

二重コメント以外にも、まだSOの仕様に慣れていなくてコメントが細切れになっているようなケースを見かけますが、それらが特に重大な問題を抱えているとは思えないので基本は「**そのまま放置**」でいいのではないでしょうか。もしくはコメントで本人に指摘してみる程度でいいでしょう。

「通報」は「放置することで誰かが被害や不利益を被るような行為」があり、かつ「ユーザーだけでは解決できない場合」に使用するべきで、むやみにやたらに使用するのは適切ではありません。

Comment: なるほど、大変よくわかりました。

Answer (score 3):

スタックオーバーフローの投稿の中で、唯一、信用度を重ねるだけではモデレーション対象にできないのがコメントです。システム的には、「通報」によって不要なコメントを報告し、モデレータがそれを「削除」する、という形で整理していくのが想定されています。

個人的には、不要なコメントであれば、割と積極的に削除するべきである、とは考えています。というのも、例えばとある時点では正しく動いていた回答とそのコードに対して、その数年後、「ライブラリのバージョンアップにより最新版ではエラーになります」といったような情報を付与したくなる場合、その場合はコメントで投稿するのが妥当かなと考えています。

コメントが永久に削除されないと今度は何が起こるかというと、そのような最新の（有益な）コメントを発見しづらくなる、という不都合が発生します。コメントは、設計として、[質問または回答に残される「付箋」のメモ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) であるように作られていると思っています。ですので、不要なコメントを見かけたならば、モデレータが「その付箋を剥がせるように」通報するのがいいのではないかな、と個人的には思っています。

しかし、あまりアグレッシブに削除しすぎると、「つい昨日やりとりしていた私のコメントが消えた！？何故？」と、コミュニティメンバーに混乱を与えてしまうようだ、とも思っています。コメントをどの程度の基準で削除していくかの基準はまだこれまでなかった、という認識なので、上がってきた「コメントが不要である」通報に対しては、ケースバイケースで削除するかどうかを決めています。

Comment: なるほど、モデレーターの方自身の意見ということもあり、大変参考になりました。